# permutation test on throwing three dice with sides labelled in a binary way

Tags: r, random, permutation

I want to model throwing three, six-sided dice permuted n number of times (say 6,000 times), where each die has three sides labelled 1 and 0.

I want to test whether three dice getting either all 1s or all 0s ~600/6000 times is more than expected by chance, but don't know how to do it on R.

I am happy to receive relevant links to tutorials also
(this didn't help much: https://docs.tibco.com/pub/enterprise-runtime-for-R/4.0.2/doc/html/Language_Reference/base/sample.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Throwing a die with 3 ones and three zeros is the same as throwing a fair coin, so we can model this using a binomial distribution.

```
dbinom(0:3, 3, 0.5)
# 0.125 0.375 0.375 0.125
```

Here you can see that getting all ones or all zeros has a probability of 0.125 each, or 0.25, one fourth, combined.

Knowing this null probability we can test how probable the outcome you saw was.

```
binom.test(600, 6000, p=0.25)
```

Conclusion: you getting all ones or all zeros in 600 out of 6000 rolls given a fair set of three dice is very unlikely. You'd expect around 1500.

Answer (score 1):

This should meet your needs:

```
set.seed(0)
die1 <- sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 6000, replace = T)
die2 <- sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 6000, replace = T)
die3 <- sample(c(0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), 6000, replace = T)
sum(die1 == die2 & die2 == die3)
```

Comment: In this answer, there is nearly no body text at all, so while I don't feel strongly about my edit, the answer nevertheless could do with some improvement. Currently this is a "code only answer"; could you edit the introduction to explain _why_ the presented code might meet the needs of the OP?